# Best way to execute an huge query

Tags: database

Let me share a very simple question for you. Imagine this situation.

Table 1: pk1, field11, field12,field13,field14

Table 2: pk2,field21, field2,field23,field24

Table 3: pk3, field31,field32,field33,field34

and this relationship:

field11 = pk2

field24=pk3

And we need: field11, field12, field, 23,field24, field 31,field34

In this 3 tables can be 1 million of nodes in each one.

I was thinking about to solve it with 2 inner join but maybe any other solution for this kind of huge query?

Regards,

Jose

Answer (score 0):

Even if you torture your query by a contorted code, the fact that a query is translated in an algebraic formulae will produce the same execution plan because the mathematical simplification process will ends up to the same mathematical expression (the optimizer do the job for you).

So, do not torture your mind, simplify your life, and write simple queries without thinking what is expected to be the best !